# SBT - Always coming up with unresolved dependency error

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I've been trying to modify the [Fratboi](https://github.com/VirenMohindra/Fratboi) language (which itself is based on the [ArnoldC](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC) language), and I can't seem to get either one to build, even when I've made no modifications to the source code.

I've been following the instructions in the Fratboi repository, but can't seem to actually compile the language into the handy .jar file that you're supposed to use when running the language.

This is the error:

```
sbt compile
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/user/workspace/Fratboi/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/user/workspace/Fratboi/project/}fratboi-build...
[warn]  module not found: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0//1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/    scala_2.12/sbt_1.0//1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/user/.ivy2/local/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0//1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.12_1.0/1.6.0/sbt-    idea-1.6.0.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/user/.sbt/preloaded/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/user/.sbt/preloaded/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.12_1.0/1.6.0/sbt-idea-1.6.0.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.1
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0//0.14.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/    scala_2.12/sbt_1.0//0.14.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/user/.ivy2/local/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0//0.14.1/ivys/    ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.12_1.0/0.14.1/sbt-    assembly-0.14.1.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/user/.sbt/preloaded/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/0.14.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/user/.sbt/preloaded/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.12_1.0/0.14.1/sbt-    assembly-0.14.1.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these     dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.6.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.1 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.6.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/    home/user/workspace/Fratboi/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:fratboi-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.1 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/home/user/workspace/Fratboi/project/plugins.sbt#L3-4)
[warn]        +- default:fratboi-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.1: not found
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve        (IvyActions.scala:331)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1    (IvyActions.scala:205)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1    (Ivy.scala:229)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:190)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$    $action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1    (Locks.scala:78)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:185)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:182)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:228)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:190)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update    (IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:38)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12    (LibraryManagement.scala:91)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:64)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19    (LibraryManagement.scala:104)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11    (LibraryManagement.scala:104)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted    (LibraryManagement.scala:87)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:141)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:118)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2313)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)    
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.s    cala:257)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$ano    nfun$submitValid$1    (ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)    
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)    
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPool        Executor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:     com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.1: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using sbt 1.0, and those two sbt plugins are not (yet?) published for that version. Try with sbt 0.13.x and you should be able to resolve them.

Comment: sbt-assembly 0.14.5 works with SBT 1.0. sbt-idea is not needed anymore as Idea supports sbt projects natively now